# How to stay in the this context during an ajax call (jquery + coffescript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, coffeescript

I made a class :

```
class @GameMap
    options : {
        'width' : 100,
        'height' : 100,
        'tileWidth' : 45,
        'tileHeight' : 20,
        'scale' : 5,
        'moveDistance' : 100, #Distance to move with the map controlers
        'showErrorMessages' : true,
        'zindexDecorElementBase' : 99999,
        'zindexGroudElementBase' : 88888
    }

    lang : {
        'errContainerMissing' : "L'élement pour créer la carte n'existe pas"
    }

    constructor: (@element) ->
      this.run()

    run: ->
      this.loadDatas()

    loadDatas: (top,left) ->
      $.ajax(
          url: "/map/getnewcoord",
          data: {
             map_width : this.options.width,
             map_height : this.options.height,
             tile_height : this.options.tileHeight,
             tile_width : this.options.tileWidth,
             window_large : $('.map-windows').width(),
             window_height:  $('.map-windows').height(),
             top : top ,
             left : left
          },
          success: (data) ->
            $.each(data,(index,item) ->
              this.createTile(item.posX,item.posY);
            )
      )

    createTile: (m,n) ->
       #We are in the tile reference
       yDelta = Math.round((options.width ) * options.tileHeight );
       console.log('pass')

  $ ->
    gamemap = new GameMap("#map .block-map")
```

But i got the error

> this.createTile is not a function

It's because the "this" is not the "this" of my class but one of item return by my json call.

How can i do to keep the "this" of my class in the ajax success callback function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the CoffeeScript way to do it:

```
      success: (data) =>
        $.each(data,(index,item) =>
          this.createTile(item.posX,item.posY);
        )
```

This compiles to something very similar to alex's answer, but is, I think, much more readable.  The `=>` operator defines a function while using the `this` that was present when it was defined, rather than when it was called.

While we're at it, you may find it more readable to use `@` instead of `this`:

```
          @createTile(item.posX,item.posY);
```

Comment: The "fat arrow" explaination in CoffeScript's documentation: http://coffeescript.org/#fat_arrow

Answer (score 3):

Keep a reference to `this`.

A lot of people use a pattern such as `var that = this` (or `self` if it reads better for you).

Then, in your inner function, replace references to `this` with `that`, which will be the parent function's `this`.

Alternatively, you can wrap the anonymous function definitions with [`$.proxy()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/)...

```
fn = $.proxy(fn, this);
```

...which will ensure the `this` inside is always the parent's `this`. `$.proxy()` is a cross browser way of achieving `bind()` (which isn't implemented in the older IEs or Safari).

Comment: I would suggest using self. self = this, self.createTile. It's more intuitive

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the `context` as param to the `ajax()` method:

```
$.ajax({ /*...,*/ context: this/*, ...*/ });
```

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: Thank you but the problem came from the each function which does not keep the this context.

Comment: So, you can mix my answer with alex's. Or use his solution istead.