# calling a method from jquery callback with coffeescript

Tags: javascript, jquery, coffeescript

In coffescript, I want to call a class method from a jquery callback, how do I access the class's scope? this.loadImage(currentIndex) doesnt work

```
class ImageCarousel    

    currentIndex = 0
    jsonPath = "json/images.json"
    images = null  


    constructor: () ->

       this.loadJson()


loadJson: () ->

    $.ajax jsonPath,
        success  : (data, status, xhr) ->
            console.log("yea "+data)
            this.images = data.images
            this.loadImage(currentIndex)
        error    : (xhr, status, err) ->
            console.log("nah "+err)
        complete : (xhr, status) ->
            console.log("comp")




loadImage:(@index) ->

    console.log("load image "+@index)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to stay in the this context during an ajax call (jquery + coffescript)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8552270/how-to-stay-in-the-this-context-during-an-ajax-call-jquery-coffescript)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use the `=>` operator for your callback.  You might find [this info](http://coffeescriptcookbook.com/chapters/jquery/callback-bindings-jquery) helpful.