# How to keep the parent's context in CoffeeScript during an AJAX request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, coffeescript, scope

I want to go through an object in CoffeeScript and for every single item in that object I want to make an AJAX call (using jQuery). In the callback mechanism of the AJAX call I want to print then the data of the item that has caused the request but in my callback I lose the reference to the initial context. The context is always the same:

```
data = 
  one: 
    id: 1
  two:
    id: 2
  three:
    id: 3
  four:
    id: 4
  five:
    id: 5

callback = (data, textStatus, jqXHR) ->    
  console.log value.id # It's always "5" :-(

for key, value of data
  $.get ".", callback
```

How can I keep the context? I already tried it with the `fat arrow` for my callback but this wasn't helpful. [I read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8552270) that there is something called `$.proxy` but how to use it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can also wrap it in an immediate function and store a variable in this context:

```
for key, value of data
  (->
    val = value
    callback = (data, textStatus, jqXHR) ->    
      console.log val.id
    $.get ".", callback
  )()
```

Notice that with this method, you have to first declare the callback before calling it.

But propably the most "coffeescript way", is with the **do** keyword, which immediately invokes a passed function, forwarding any arguments:

```
for key, value of data
  do (value)->
    callback = (data, textStatus, jqXHR) ->    
      console.log value.id
    $.get ".", callback
```

---

Another way for achieving this, is using jQuery's [each](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) function for iterating:

```
$.each data, (index, value) ->
  callback = (data, textStatus, jqXHR) ->    
    console.log value.id
  $.get ".", callback
```

Comment: That was very helpful. Thank you!! I like the use of $.each

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I solved the issue with replacing `$.get` with `$.ajax` and then using the `context` property. But is there also a CoffeeScript-way to do it? Because my solution depends on jQuery.

```
data = 
  one: 
    id: 1
  two:
    id: 2
  three:
    id: 3
  four:
    id: 4
  five:
    id: 5

callback = (data, textStatus, jqXHR) ->    
  console.log @id

for key, value of data
  $.ajax
    url: "."
    type: "GET"
    context: @value
  .always(callback)
```